# Meaning of 'Or What', 'What it takes to be'

Tags: meaning

I'm learning english using 'Phineas and Ferb'.

This situation is
before introducing some auditions(like American idol),
there is one singing tone-def person.

After singing, the dj was like,

> Oh, boy! Did that kid stink or what?
>   But maybe you've got what it takes to be
>   The Next Super American Pop Teen Idol Star!

I didn't know these two sentence.

In first sentence,
`Stink` means bad smell? And what's the meaning of `or what?`?

In second sentence,
What's the meaning of `it takes to be`?

Comment: @cobaltduck What quote? There is no attributed source. (Yes, it's from an epsiode of the cartoon—but there should be a link to a video clip or a transcript.) Looking only at the sentences, *what it takes* on its own is fine. But adding only *to be* is strange. It seems like it's missing something like *what it takes to be* ***a star***.

Comment: @cobaltduck Gotcherback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've actually asked two questions, about two separate idioms, so I will answer them independently.

First, the "or what?" is an expression added to a statement to which one expects agreement, generally to add emphasis, or to challenge another to disagree.  You are essentially saying, "If what I say is not the case, than what is?"  [Idioms By Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/or+what%3F) gives us these definitions:

> Added to a yes-no question as a means of emphasizing that "yes" is the correct answer.
>
> a way of adding emphasis to a yes-or-no question the speaker has asked. (In effect, if it wasn't what I said, what is it?)

To paraphrase the announcer's "Did that kid stink or what?" I might say, "That kid's performance was really horrible.  Does anyone disagree?"

---

Now the second part, "what it takes."  This idiom refers to having either the skills and abilities, or possibly the will and determination, to accomplish a task.  Again turning to [Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/what+it+takes) for definitions:

> The skill, ability, or wherewithal to do something.
>
> The necessary expertise or qualities needed for success.

Paraphrasing the announcer this time, I would say, "Maybe you are talented and determined enough to compete on this show?"

Comment: Awesome! I understood easy because of your paraphrasing. Thank you.